# what is the most efficient way of unlocking a LUKS drive over the network when using key files?

Tags: ssh, luks

It is easy to unlock a LUKS drive over SSH when the drive takes text passwords:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 mylockeddrive
```

Then entering the password at prompt.

Is there a way of unlocking these drives when a key file is used, short of copying the key file on the remote system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Send the key via a pipe and tell cryptsetup to read it from standard input.

```
cat keyfile | ssh remotehost "cryptsetup open --type luks --key-file - /dev/sdb1"
```